# How to use "open" command in VSC?

Tags: python, file, visual-studio-code

I use VSC Version:1.36.1. 
I want to run simple code, in VSC, that opens file and write smth into. But nothing happens. When i use the same code in Notepad++ everything works fine, file is created with "12345" in it.

Code:

```
f = open('My_text.txt', 'w')
f.write("12345")
f.close()
```

There is no errors, the program is being executed. No text file is created. What should i do? Is there any option in VSC that can help ( im new with that program and still learning ).

Comment: Did you run the script? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_run-hello-world

Comment: Im running code in VSC terminal.

Comment: Ok, my fault. The file is created but in another folder from my last work. I haven't read the exact comments in the terminal